# How to ensure Cordova App can only be installed on a mobile phone and not on tablets?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, app-store-connect

I have a Cordova app I only want users on phones to be able to download. Is there a way to restrict the build so it won't show up in the store when the user is on an iPad or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, include this setting in your config.xml

```
<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />
```

See the cordova documentation at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/config.html

Full disclosure and attribution, I discovered this from an answer on the [ionic forums here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/remove-ipad-support-from-project-only-support-phones/37935/2) (suitable for all cordova builds not just ionic framework)

Answer (score -1):

You might also want to pickup iPhone on the Deployment Info section in xCode.
By default, it's set on Universal.